# Dog leg hyperextension

Tags: dogs, injury, surgery

So my dog jumped off a ledge 5 months ago and appears to have torn his wrist ligament. He's a 7yo 115lb tamaskan. X-rays didn't show any breakage but it's been 5 months and he's still limping though not as bad as he did back then. Sometimes it's not even noticeable. He still can't run as much and lies down pretty fast. But normal pace walking he can do an hour easy, that's how long it takes me to walk around the neighborhood. I can't tell if it's hurting because he doesn't really show it other than a slight limp. But otherwise he's a happy active dog.

I can't decide if I want to spend the quoted $7000 on surgery or try braces again (he takes them right off). Has anyone had that happen to their dog? I've read that some heal ok on their own and some don't hurt at all even with the wrist not supported by ligaments. I don't know if I should just give it more time cuz I'm really hesitant to completely immobilize the joint through fusion.